# is there any difference between doing multiple commits and a single push v/s each commit along with push

Tags: linux, git, git-commit, git-push

Is there a difference in git repo if we do the following 2 cases:

- case 1: do 10 commits and a single push at the end
- case 2: do one commit and a push, repeat the steps 10 times for each commit

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the number of contributors and the merge policy of the remote repository.

1. Only one contributor and the policy is allowing direct push.

   The difference is just the times you run the push command. The final code and history will be the same in both ways.
2. More than one contributors and the policy is allowing direct push.

   If you push 10 commits via one push, it's either success because of fast-forward push or failure because of non-fast-forward push. If you push one commit, you have more chances to fail because of non-fast-forward push. Between your two pushes, the remote branch could be updated by other contributors, which makes your local branch diverged with the remote one and your next push will fail before you do a fetch and merge/rebase. "A fetch and merge/rebase" can be done in a single command `git pull` or `git pull --rebase`.
3. The merge policy is only allowing to merge/rebase a pull-request.

   If there's only one contributor, it's not likely for you to adopt such a policy. So we just talk about a team. You will face such situation if your team is using a review tool like Gerrit. After your push, the new commits are not instantly merged into the remote branch. Every commit is kept in a ref used by Gerrit, for example a ref like `refs/changes/34/12234/1`. After reviewers review your changes and approve, these refs are then merged into the real branch. If the reviewers don't think it's qualified, then the ref is rejected. You must either amend it or reset to a previous commit, make a new commit, and push it again. A new ref will be created to be reviewed. A pull-request in Github is not exactly the same but very similar.

   In this case your push will always succeed even if it's a non-fast-forward push, because you don't actually push to the real branch. Gerrit leads your push to create other refs. If you push 10 commits in one push, 10 refs will be created and all are dependent. You can merge them one by one from the oldest to the youngest. If there is any conflict, you can either fix it, or skip it and rebase their successors.

   If you push one commit and push the next after the previous is approved and merged, other team members could push and merge their commits between your two pushes. Likewise, you could have more chances to fail because your next merge is always possible to raise a conflict. The longer the interval between the two pushes is, the more chances to fail. Of course, a `git pull` or `git pull --rebase` before every push will reduce the possibility because most potential conflicts can be fixed in the local. But not all can be avoided because whenever a ref is to be merged, the real branch could have been updated by others just a second ago.

   The real situations are more complex and the difference can be huge.

Answer (score 1):

In the End Result: No. In the interim, the multiple pushes will put the intermediate commits there sooner. But at the end of the 10th push vs the single, you'll have 10 commits pushed.

This is easy enough to test yourself.

If your computer crashed before you made the single commit, however, you'd lose more work than if you pushed incrementally.
Or, a fellow contributor might have more merge conflicts, or at least have a greater delay in getting access to your incremental changes.

Where you would have a difference is if you made 10 changes, making a single commit per chang, vs 10 changes in a single commit.

Comment: I'd add that while pushing incrementally does offer many benefits, it also has costs, for example, you can no longer safely use history cleanup features like rebase.